# Polygon/polygon zonal statistics

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I have two polygon layers. One is counties, one is drought severity. I want to compute what fraction of each county is at each of five levels of drought severity. I've looked at "Join Attributes by Location (summary), and Overlap Analysis and neither seems to do what I want. I can union the two layers, remove the features that don't overlap the original county layer, then compute areas and then compute the fraction at each severity level for each county feature.

Is there a processing algorithm or another approach that does this in one step?

Comment: You could do it in two steps with a Split Vector Layer (on severity) then use the split severity layers as the Overlay Layers inputs to Overlap Analysis.

Comment: @user2856 - Thanks - that's an improvement over the approach I described. Minor quibble - it's actually three steps. You have to load the layers created by the Split Vector Layer algorithm.

Comment: Yeah 3. Overlay Layers could be improved with a "zone fields" type of parameters, ala ["Tabulate Intersection"](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/tabulate-intersection.htm) ArcGIS tool

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for, except in qgis.